# Image as variable in Actionscript 3

Tags: image, actionscript-3, variables

How can I set png images from library as variables? How should I declare and set them?I'm trying to create an array of Images. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried converting them to `MovieClip`? You can set the export for actionscript settings in the `MovieClip`properties once they are `MovieClip`. That will allow you to use them as a variable. Otherwise you would have to load them in as bitmaps, which would require a few extra steps.

Answer (score 3):

Right click the image in the library, click ActionScript and check 'Export in frame 1'. Then give the image a class name.

[image]

The class name can be used to create instances of [`BitmapData`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html):

```
var data:BitmapData = new MyImage();
```

Which can be used to display `Bitmap`s like so:

```
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(data);
//                             ^^^^ Refers to above BitmapData.

addChild(bitmap);
```

Comment: @Cherniv Yes, you can use `[Embed]` to do this using ActionScript but the OP specifically mentions use of the library.

Comment: Here's an [article](http://www.developria.com/2010/02/dealing-with-bitmapdata.html) that goes into some depth about how the above steps work.